# Prove or counterexample: A closed and totally bounded set $A$ in a metric space must be compact.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I think for some time and now I agree that the statement is false. But I cannot prove or disprove the statement.

I know that compact $\Leftrightarrow$ complete+totally bounded, and also "bounded and totally bounded are the same in $\Bbb R^n$".

So I aim to find a not complete metric space which is closed and totally bounded. Could someone please help? If such an example exists, may I please ask for finding one in $\Bbb R^n$ (or other easy examples are also appreciate).

If the statement is correct, may I please ask for a proof?

Comment: $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Should be $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. This set isn't closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: More generally, any set $A$ is closed in $A$, so to have a counterexample you only have to consider a set $A$ that is totally bounded but not compact : for example, any closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not bounded is a counterexample.

Comment: @Przemek I intended to mean "in the subspace topology wrt $\Bbb R$" but yes, you are right, my wording was bad.

Comment: @tristan So may I take $(0,1]$ in $((0,1],d_{\Bbb R})$ where $d_{\Bbb R}$ is the standard norm in $\Bbb R$ as a counterexample? I think this set is totally bounded, $(0,1]$ in $((0,1],d_{\Bbb R})$ is closed, but it is not compact. (For instance, the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ in this space has no convergent sequence.)

Comment: @PropositionX Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you should try to prove:

> If $A$ is a closed subset of a complete metric space $(X,d),$ then letting $d'$ be the restriction of $d$ to $A\times A,$ we have that $(A,d')$ is a complete metric space.

It isn't too tricky. Consequently, a closed, totally bounded subset of a complete metric space will be compact, so if you're looking for counterexamples, you shouldn't look in euclidean spaces or other complete metric spaces.

The comments give a nice example of a closed, totally bounded subset of $\Bbb Q$ that does the trick, though.

Answer (score 2):

Statement in your question is correct if you replace "metric space" by "$\mathbb{R}^n$" and this is precisely content of the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

If you want $Y=\overline Y\subset X$ where   $Y$ is  totally bounded but not compact, then, as pointed out in the Answer by Cameron Buie, $d$ cannot be a complete metric on $X.$  So in particular we cannot have $X=\mathbb R^n$ with the usual metric.

However we may take $Y=X$ if $d$ is an incomplete metric on $X$ and $(X,d)$ is a totally bounded metric space. For example let $X$ be the real interval $(0,1)$ with $d(u,v)=|u-v|. $